# Is there a way to tell gcc to read the program from the keyboard?

Tags: gcc, console

Like the old DOS way of creating a file by writing "copy con foo.txt", I want to type in "gcc ..." and just get to writing a short C++ program. Is there a way to tell gcc that's what we're doing?

Comment: Why? Would you really ever do this? Is the extra step of _writing a file_ so onerous?

Comment: Why would you not just feed it a text file? The user can quickly type in a program and save it to a text file, then you feed that to the compiler... Why complicate things?

Comment: While I've provided an answer below, I mostly agree with the comments here. You might think that these are just little throw away programs that you would never want to keep. But keeping all of your experiments around is a great way to build up a personal library of examples to refer to later when you've forgotten how something worked, or use to help other people, or answer questions when they are covering the same ground you explored. Even better, make it a DVCS repo so you never lose the history.

Comment: Why? It's for a wedding script. The groom and the officiant are joking about having Code Captions for the English-impaired. This would be the opening line before the rest of the captions start.

Comment: And if you think that's silly, wait 'til we get to "#typedef union {} marriage".

Comment: Hah. OK. In that case, carry on! Sounds like a fun wedding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use '-' to tell gcc to read from stdin. Since gcc won't know what language you are going to type in, you need to tell it the language with the -x command line flag. In this example, straight C:

```
~$ gcc -x c -
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    return 0;
}
~$ ./a.out 
Hello, World
```

For C++, use `g++ -x c++ -`. You need to invoke the g++ driver for C++ so that it knows to link the C++ runtime.

Comment: `gcc -x c++ -` or `g++ -`, the OP asked for C++